# How to create h:commandButton in JSF to open a new page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to create command button in JSF page. When I press it I want to open a new page and send a value using using the http. I tested this `h:commnadButton` but it's not working.

```
<h:commandButton id="lnkHidden" value=" Edit User " action="EditAccountProfile.jsf">
 <f:param name="id" value="#{item.userid}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`h:commandButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) is for submitting forms, usually executing actions in the server.

Use [`h:button`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) for simple navigation:

```
<h:button id="lnkHidden" value=" Edit User " outcome="EditAccountProfile.jsf">
 <f:param name="id" value="#{item.userid}" />
</h:button>
```

This will generate a normal HTML `<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href=/correct/path/to/EditAccountProfile.jsf" />`, no HTTP POST needed.

**See also:**

[When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)