# Still on the same page after submitting data

Tags: jsf

I need a understanding. Why did i find my self still on the same page when submitting some inputs in JSF file , have a look :

```
<!--<b>codes below belong to <i>page1.xhtml</i></b>-->      
   <h:form>
        <table>
           <tr> 
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{user.name}"/></td>
            </tr>
         </table>   
    </h:form>
    <p><h:commandButton value="Login" action="page2"/></p>
```

After pressing "Login" , it showed value of `#{user.name}` from `page2.xhtml`, but the link itself is still `faces/page1.xhtml`  , why not `faces/page2.xhtml` ? Could someone explain it to me ? does it mean that in JSF we access everything just from one page?

I try to make something like this :

```
<h:form action="page2.xhtml">
```

but then i realize there is no such "action" on `"<h:form>"` tag

Comment: you must refer to this page to get your answer
I think this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670129/how-to-create-hcommandbutton-in-jsf-to-open-a-new-page

Comment: The `action` button must be set in `h:commandButton` and not in `h:fom`. You still don't mention which version of JSF are you working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the answers to this question:  [How to make URL reflect the current page (and not the previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one).

In your example I would say you ideally would want to use the option

```
Send a redirect after POST.
For example, showing list of all data after successful create/update/delete, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

in JSF when you submit a value it's normally to a java bean: a class who process the information,to creat a bean you could you use a code like this:

```
package beans

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class SignInBean {

private String username;

//getter and setter for username

  public void register(){
    //add to data base
    //redirect to new page
  }
}
```

and in th xhtml file

```
<h:inputText value="#{signInBean.username}"/>

<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{signInBean.register"/>
```

Comment: this is kinda good solution too, but redirecting to a new page from bean class is just something that i haven't learnt before..

Comment: this how you do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955130/jsf-page-redirecting-from-java-bean
It can be very useful if you redirect to multiple pages depending on a certain condition